# Cmake "ld.exe:cannot open linker script file"

Tags: c, cmake, linker, cross-compiling, stm32

I generated a project by the STMCubeMX and wanted to import this project into Clion.

Here's the `CmakeList.txt`:

```
project(ClionTest)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

add_definitions(-DSTM32F4xx)

file(GLOB_RECURSE USER_SOURCES "Src/*.c")
file(GLOB_RECURSE HAL_SOURCES "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/*.c")

add_library(CMSIS
        startup/startup_stm32f407xx.s)

include_directories(Drivers/CMSIS/Device)
include_directories(Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include)
include_directories(Drivers/CMSIS/Include)
include_directories(Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver)
include_directories(Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc)
include_directories(Inc)
include_directories(Middlewares/Third_Party/LwIP/src/include)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}.elf ${USER_SOURCES} ${HAL_SOURCES} ${LINKER_SCRIPT})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}.elf CMSIS)

set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,-Map=${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/${PROJECT_NAME}.map")
set(HEX_FILE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/${PROJECT_NAME}.hex)
set(BIN_FILE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/${PROJECT_NAME}.bin)
add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}.elf POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} -Oihex $<TARGET_FILE:${PROJECT_NAME}.elf> ${HEX_FILE}
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} -Obinary $<TARGET_FILE:${PROJECT_NAME}.elf> ${BIN_FILE}
        COMMENT "Building ${HEX_FILE} \nBuilding ${BIN_FILE}")
```

And a `STM32F4xx.cmake` file:

```
INCLUDE(CMakeForceCompiler)

SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)

# specify the cross compiler
#CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER(C:/Program Files (x86)/GNU Tools ARM Embedded/6 2017-q2-update/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe GNU)
#CMAKE_FORCE_CXX_COMPILER(D:/Lib/arm/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++.exe GNU)

SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "C:/Program Files (x86)/GNU Tools ARM Embedded/6 2017-q2-update/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "C:/Program Files (x86)/GNU Tools ARM Embedded/6 2017-q2-update/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++.exe")

SET(LINKER_SCRIPT ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/STM32F407VETx_FLASH.ld)
#Uncomment for software floating point
#SET(COMMON_FLAGS "-mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mthumb-interwork -mfloat-abi=soft -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -g -fno-common -fmessage-length=0")
SET(COMMON_FLAGS "-mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mthumb-interwork -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -g -fno-common -fmessage-length=0")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT "${COMMON_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_INIT "${COMMON_FLAGS} -std=gnu99")
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT "-Wl,-gc-sections,-M=binary.map -T ${LINKER_SCRIPT}")
```

I set `LINKER_SCRIPT ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/STM32F407VETx_FLASH.ld`

[File structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W21hE.png)

And the Cmake options is:

[Cmake options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aG0y1.png)

When I reload this project, it's not go on well.

```
c:/progra~2/gnutoo~1/62017-~1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: cannot open linker script file
D:/Project/ClionTest/cmake-build-default/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/STM32F407VETx_FLASH.ld:
  Invalid argument

  collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

  CMakeFiles\cmTC_bf7b4.dir\build.make:96: recipe for target 'cmTC_bf7b4' failed

  mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [cmTC_bf7b4] Error 1

  mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory
  'D:/Project/ClionTest/cmake-build-default/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

  Makefile:125: recipe for target 'cmTC_bf7b4/fast' failed

  mingw32-make.exe: *** [cmTC_bf7b4/fast] Error 2
```

It seems like the path of `ld.exe` is not correct,how shoulld I set its path?
And why the path of `STM32F407VETx_FLASH.ld` it searched is not the path I set?

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Linux, but I've had the a similar issue in regards to being unable to open the linker script.

> `cannot open linker script file D:/Project/ClionTest/cmake-build-default/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/STM32F407VETx_FLASH.ld`

After looking for a while at the documentation for [target_link_option](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_options.html) (which does approximately the same kind of thing as setting a variable directly), I took note of the `SHELL:` directive, that's stated to:

> The set of options is de-duplicated to avoid repetition. While beneficial for individual options, the de-duplication step can break up option groups. For example, -D A -D B becomes -D A B. One may specify a group of options using shell-like quoting along with a SHELL: prefix. The SHELL: prefix is dropped and the rest of the option string is parsed using the separate_arguments() UNIX_COMMAND mode.

By adding it to my command, I managed to get compilation working normally. The result was the following:

```
set(LINKER_SCRIPT "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/STM32F303CCTX_FLASH.ld")
set(LINKER_FLAGS "SHELL:-T${LINKER_SCRIPT} -Wl,--gc-sections --specs=nano.specs --specs=nosys.specs")
target_link_options(${PROJECT_BINARY} PRIVATE ${LINKER_FLAGS})
```

Answer (score -1):

Change this:
`SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT "-Wl,-gc-sections,-M=binary.map -T ${LINKER_SCRIPT}")`

To:
`SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,-gc-sections,-M=binary.map -T${LINKER_SCRIPT}")`

Comment: Your answer would benefit from an explanation.

Comment: Is it because CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS contains more flags than the default stored in  CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT?

Comment: Take out the space between the "T" and the linker file name